# Formatting date in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

My template renders the tag `{{ test.date}}` in the following format -

`2015-12-15T23:55:33.422679`

When I try to format it using django's built in template tag `date`, it doesn't display anything.

Variations I've tried:

`{{ test.date|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}`

`{{ test.date|date:"D d M Y" }}`

models.py:

```
class Human(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='',blank=False)


class Test(models.Model):
    human = models.ForeignKey(Human)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

views.py:

```
def list(request):
    h = Human.objects.all()
    s=[]
    for her in h: 
        t = h.test_set.all()
        s.extend(t)
    context = RequestContext(request, {'test_list': s,})
    return render_to_response('template.html', context)
```

I am then using it in template like this:

```
{% for test in test_list %}
     {{test.date}}
{% endfor %}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: looks well, what you see without using `|date :` ? Can you add view in question

Comment: you should put your code in question

Comment: What is `test.date` here? Is it an actual datetime object, or is it a string timestamp?

Comment: @DanielRoseman edited the code. Please check.

Comment: @Baterson Edited.Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want from this logic, but I think you can use this:

```
def list(request):
    test = Test.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'test':test})
```

and in template:

```
{% for t in test %}
    {% t.date %}
{% endfor %}
```

if you want display human, just add in cycle `{% t.human.name %}`

Comment: How is your code different? I'm doing the same thing. Passing a list of tests as `test_list` and then using `test.date`

Comment: @qwertp It is more cleare and simple and it will work, if you created `Test` objects

Comment: But that is not my problem. My problem is that I can't format `test.date` using the `date` template tag. I want to know if the solution can be had using a queryset of test objects

Comment: What you see in `test.date`, without template tag `date|`?.  In django 1.8 like i now, this template tage will work. Try my solution please, in my project it works. Here some tags for `datetime` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Answer (score 8):

Answering an OLD post... but, the answer doesn't seem (to me) to be answering the original question - which was WHY isn't the Django inline template date formatting working...

The answer is (I believe) that the author was trying to output to his page something like:

```
"This is my date:{{test.date|date:"D d M Y"}}."
```

The problem, if this is truly what was being tried, is that the double quotes don't work in this situation.  You need to do the following instead:

```
"This is my date:{{test.date|date:'D d M Y'}}."
```

Note the single quotes...

Comment: [Django doc for the `date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date)